# C++17: Deducing function noexcept specifier as non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, noexcept

I've noticed that MSVC sometimes fails to deduce non-type parameters that other compilers accept, and recently came upon a simple example involving the function noexcept specifier (which is part of the function's signature since C++17):

```
template <typename T> struct is_nocv_method : public std::false_type { };

template <typename ReturnT, typename ClassT, bool IsNoexcept, typename... Args>
struct is_nocv_method<ReturnT (ClassT::*)(Args...) noexcept(IsNoexcept)> : std::true_type { };
```

Godbolt suggests gcc 12.1 and clang 14.0 accept this without issue, but MSVC 14.31 (cl.exe 19.31) fails to compile, claiming `IsNoexcept` cannot be deduced. Is this a compiler defect?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vbbcoqca5)

Comment: "(which is part of the function's signature since C++17)" Technically, it's part of the function's _type_, but not its signature (IIRC). Don't think this has anything to do with your issue though; just nitpicking.

Comment: Unrelated: Nice type trait!

Comment: @TedLyngmo In case someone does write a real trait like this, I'll mention that this example doesn't include the somewhat-obscure `&` and `&&` ref-qualifiers that would also need their own specializations (and of course `const` and `volatile`, but this is a 'nocv' variant).

Comment: _MSVC 14.31_ Do you really mean that?  That would be very old.  What does `cl.exe` report, when run with no command line arguments?

Comment: @PaulSanders He's referring to the version of the Visual C++ toolset as a whole, not specifically `cl` (which has its own distinct internal version)

Comment: I agree, the `cl` version is less confusing. It should be clearer now.

Comment: @TSmith (+ OP) OK, thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-type template parameter cannot be deduced from a *noexcept-specifier*.

[[temp.deduct.type]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#8) gives the list of contexts from which template parameters can be deduced. Essentially, it can be read as a list of ways to "unwrap" the argument type, and a list of positions in the unwrapped type from which template arguments can be deduced.

For example, the item `T (T::*)(T)` implies that if the parameter type and the argument type are both pointers to member functions, then template parameters can be deduced from the return type, the class type, and any argument types (for the member function), should they appear there.

You'll notice that there is no item of the form `T() noexcept(i)`, `T(T) noexcept(i)`, and so on.

Yet, some compilers choose to allow this kind of deduction anyway, probably because it is convenient. I would support adding it to the standard.

*Edit (Oct 20, 2022):* It appears that this will be changing in C++23: `i` will be deducible from `noexcept(i)`. According to [the issues list](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2355), this has "DR" status, which means it's retroactive (presumably to C++17).

Comment: Agree. It'd be nice and would go well with [P0012R1](https://wg21.link/P0012R1) _"Make exception specifications part of the type system"_ which is already part of C++17.

Answer (score 4):

See this bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/noexcept-is-not-deducible-in-partial-spe/841571

And this issue, approved by EWG: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1018r9.html#CWG2355

It appears that deduction from noexcept specifiers is currently nonstandard, but that's considered an oversight and is set to be fixed.

Comment: EWG [has approved](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2355.html) this change.

Comment: @DavisHerring Indeed; I've updated my answer.